# WIX Installer for camera Driver with 2 inf files

Tags: installation, components, wix, driver

I'm trying to create an installer for a camera driver that contains two inf files. What I have so far is a working installer of which the relevant part looks like this:

```
        <ComponentGroup Id="MyCamDriver1" Directory="MyCamModuleDir" Source="modules\system\camera\myCam\USBX64">
        <Component Guid="7A259B3A-E41F-460F-8311-03CD89D9A7C5" Win64="$(var.Win64)">
            <File Name="myCamusbX64.inf" KeyPath="yes" />
            <File Name="myCamusbX64.sys" />
            <File Name="myCamusbX64.cat" />
            <File Name="wdfcoinstaller01011.dll" />
            <difx:Driver DeleteFiles="yes" Legacy="yes" AddRemovePrograms="no" PlugAndPlayPrompt="no" />
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
    <!-- <ComponentGroup Id="MyCamDriver2" Directory="MyCamModuleDir" Source="modules\system\camera\myCam\CabUSBX64">  -->
    <!--     <Component Guid="91E30F1E-1C53-49FB-B31E-273CD43120BD" Win64="$(var.Win64)">                              -->
    <!--         <File Name="myCamcabusbX64.inf" KeyPath="yes" />                                                      -->
    <!--         <File Name="myCamcabusbX64.sys" />                                                                    -->
    <!--         <File Name="myCamcabusbX64.cat" />                                                                    -->
    <!--         <File Name="wdfcoinstaller01011.dll" />                                                               -->
    <!--         <difx:Driver DeleteFiles="yes" Legacy="yes" AddRemovePrograms="no" PlugAndPlayPrompt="no" />          -->
    <!--     </Component>                                                                                              -->
    <!-- </ComponentGroup>                                                                                             -->
```

Executing this installs the myCamusbX64 driver fine, also uninstalling removes everything like it should. But as soon as I add the uncommented part the installer won't be created with the error message:

Error CNDL0207 The Component element contains an unexpected child element 'difx:Driver'.  The 'difx:Driver' element may only occur 1 time(s) under the Component element.

Actually the 'difx:Driver' element **does** occur only once under the Component, doesn't it? It's even in two different Component groups. Has anybody an idea how this could be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Add explicit `Id`s to each `Component`.

Answer (score 0):

[Bob Arnson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69710002/wix-installer-for-camera-driver-with-2-inf-files/69711848#69711848) pointed me into the right direction. However I had to add some more changes. Here is what is working now for me:

```
    <ComponentGroup Id="MyCamDriverUSB" Directory="MyCamModuleDirUSB" Source="modules\system\camera\myCam\USBX64">
        <Component Id="MyCamUsbX64" Guid="7A259B3A-E41F-460F-8311-03CD89D9A7C5" Win64="$(var.Win64)">
            <File Name="myCamusbX64.inf" KeyPath="yes" />
            <File Name="myCamusbX64.sys" />
            <File Name="myCamusbX64.cat" />
            <File Id="WdfUSB" Name="wdfcoinstaller01011.dll" />
            <difx:Driver DeleteFiles="yes" Legacy="yes" AddRemovePrograms="no" PlugAndPlayPrompt="no" />
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
    <ComponentGroup Id="MyCamDriverCABUSB" Directory="MyCamModuleDirCABUSB" Source="modules\system\camera\myCam\CabUSBX64">
        <Component Id="MyCamCabUsbX64" Guid="91E30F1E-1C53-49FB-B31E-273CD43120BD" Win64="$(var.Win64)">                            
            <File Name="myCamcabusbX64.inf" KeyPath="yes" />
            <File Name="myCamcabusbX64.sys" />
            <File Name="myCamcabusbX64.cat" />                                                                  
            <File Id="WdfCABUSB" Name="wdfcoinstaller01011.dll" />                                                           
            <difx:Driver DeleteFiles="yes" Legacy="yes" AddRemovePrograms="no" PlugAndPlayPrompt="no" />        
        </Component>                                                                                            
    </ComponentGroup>
```

So additionally to Bob's recommendation of adding an Id to each component I had to add an Id to the wdfcoinstaller01011.dll elements and change the Directory element of the ComponentGroups to something unique.